# How to move /usr from one partition to another partition safely

Tags: file-copy

Linux, Debian.

Now I have:

```
/dev/sda5   on /
/dev/sda6   on /home
/dev/sda7   on /usr
```

I would like to use sda6 to hold `/usr`, then free `/dev/sda7` for other use.

What is the safest way to do this?
I am confused about how to create a `/usr` on `/dev/sda6` and issue copy command without confusing Linux.

Comment: yes you can move it to any partitions and it will get work

Comment: Do you have enough free space on `/dev/sda6` to hold all the data from both `/home` and `/usr`?

Comment: @Teddy yes,it does have enough.

Answer (score 2):

I can see no good way for two subdirectories to share a partition, except for using a symbolic link:

1. Boot in single-user mode so no processes are running.
2. Copy everything from `/usr` into `/home`

   ```
   cp --archive --sparse=always --one-file-system /usr /home
   ```
3. Unmount `/usr`, remove the empty mount point and make a symlink

   ```
   umount /usr

   rmdir /usr

   ln --symbolic /home/usr /
   ```
4. Edit `/etc/fstab` and remove (or comment out) the line with the `/usr` mount.

   ```
   sensible-editor /etc/fstab
   ```
5. Reboot

Comment: have you tested this ?

Comment: I see a way. mount `sda6` onto the root namespace, then mount `sda5` on top of that. have fun configuring the initrd for that, though.

Comment: @RahulPatil No.